# Executar método Android quando aplicação é encerrada

Tags: android

Tenho um app que faz download e envio de arquivos via ftp. Quando o app inicia ele recebe um arquivo de texto e gostaria de enviar o arquivo quando a aplicação é encerrada. Procurei sobre como fazer algo quando a aplicação encerra e achei os metodos onStop e onDestroy, mas não sei se estou fazendo da maneira certa

```
  public void onStop(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    metodo
}
```

seria chamar o metodo onStop e dentro dele realizar a atividade de envio para o servidor FTP por exemplo?

Pois chamo a atividade de download dentro do metodo onCreate e funciona bem

Comment: Use `onDestroy`, é ele que é chamado quando a `Activity` é eliminada da memória pelo Android ou quando você fecha a aplicação.

Comment: Leitura recomendada: [Entendendo o ciclo de vida de uma aplicação Android](http://www.devmedia.com.br/entendendo-o-ciclo-de-vida-de-uma-aplicacao-android/22922) e [Ciclo de vida do Fragments no Android](http://www.devmedia.com.br/ciclo-de-vida-do-fragments-no-android/33099)

Answer (score 1):

Se o android destruir o processo(por necessidade de libertar memória por exemplo), `onDestroy()` não é chamado e o mesmo se aplica a `onStop()` para aplicações pre-HONEYCOMB..

Para garantir que o arquivo é enviado faça-o no `onPause()`.

Tenha em conta que o método `onPause()` é também chamado quando a *Activity* passa para *background*`(deixa de estar visível).

Para mais informação veja [Activity .Lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle)